# How to define go structs to store this yaml structure?

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to figure out how to organize my Golang structs to store my yaml file. I think I'm having a bit of a problem with the nested maps. I'm trying to get this yaml file to be stored in something like `{statCategory:{CatOne:{featD:{description:amazing, unit:nil}}}`.

I'm currently using `yaml "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"` for parsing yaml.

Below is the yaml file that I'm trying to parse.

```
stat:
  statCategory:
    CatOne:
      featD:
        description: amazing
        unit: nil
      featH:
        description: not amazing
        unit: nil
    CatTwo:
      featA:
        description: hello
        unit: ms
      featB:
        description: something
        unit: ms
      featC:
        description: another description
        unit: ms
```

I've tried to use the struct below, but it's seem to only kinda work.

```
type yamlStatDAO struct {
    Stat statCategory `yaml:"stat"`
}
type statCategory struct {
    StatCat map[string]map[string]statInfo `yaml:"statCategory"`
}

type statInfo struct {
    description string `yaml:"description"`
    unit        string `yaml:"unit"`
}
```

But I only end up with `{statCategory:{CatOne:{featD:{}}}`. If I can't figure this out, I might just restructure my yaml file.

EDIT: seems like the solution was just to capitalize description and unit.

```
type statInfo struct {
    Description string `yaml:"description"`
    Unit        string `yaml:"unit"`
}
```

Thanks to Alexander Maru from the comments.

Comment: To populate description and unit fields in `statInfo`, capitalize the fields to `Description` and `Unit`.

Comment: Wow, that worked! Do you know the source where I would be able to find the info on this stuff?

Comment: The [yaml api documentation](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2) can be useful. More specifically, it states [here](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Unmarshal) that "*Struct fields are only unmarshalled if they are exported (have an upper case first letter), and are unmarshalled using the field name lowercased as the default key.*"